# CryptoJS Progressive Ciphering

Tags: cryptojs

Is there any other tutorial or documentation on how to do Progressive Ciphering with CryptoJS?
Their own Documentation about it is kinda lacking of Information's

These are the Information's I found:

https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#progressive-ciphering
https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/docs/QuickStartGuide.wiki

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
export function calcSha1 (file: File): Promise<string> {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const promise = new Promise<string>(
    (resolve) => {
      reader.onloadend = (evt: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
        const sha1Hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create()
        let currentPosition = 0
        const chunkSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10MB
        while (currentPosition < file.size) {
          let endPosition = currentPosition + chunkSize
          if (endPosition > file.size) {
            endPosition = file.size
          }
          const blob = evt.target?.result?.slice(currentPosition, endPosition)
          const wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(blob)
          sha1Hash.update(wordArray)
          currentPosition += chunkSize
        }
        const result = sha1Hash.finalize()
        resolve(result.toString())
      }
    }
  )
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  return promise
}
```